# images does not display at run time

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

i have come a cross weird problem in windows phone 8 as when i set the source of an image in Xaml it shows correctly in the designer view but when i run the application no image appears i have made a new empty application.

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <Image Visibility="Visible" Source="Assets\Tiles\FlipCycleTileMedium.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="321" Margin="61,192,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="359"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Image property get the good build action => Content ?

Comment: And when you put this Source="Assets\Logo.scale-100.png" the default image when you create app store. it's works?

Comment: that Assets\Logo.scale-100.png image dose not exist in my default assets folder but even when i try to put a default image from assets folder it shows only in the designer view

Comment: @MatDev8 this is Windows Phone 8 apps, not app store. And OP is already using default image from WP8 project template.

Comment: @user2918388 tested, work just fine here. Image displayed in designer as well as in emulator.

Comment: so should i repair the emulator or what

Comment: @user2918388 yeah sorry but it's the same.. when you create empty app and put this => <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Image Visibility="Visible" Source="Assets\Logo.scale-100.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="321" Margin="61,192,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="359"/>
    </Grid> What is append?

Comment: nothing shows in both designer and emulator that a blank page with the title of the application

Comment: Did you try `/Assets/Tiles/FlipCycleTileMedium.png` ? Did you check the name of `FlipCycleTileMedium.png` ?

Comment: i give it even a full path like that  c:\users\mohab\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\PhoneApp5\PhoneApp5\Assets\Tiles\FlipCycleTileLarge.png i see it only in the designer view

Comment: @user2918388 Did you move the picture outside the solution ?

Comment: It should work with the code you have. Have you tried adding your own image to the project and testing in the emulator?

Comment: Do check again... like aloisdg said, I also set the source like: Source="/Assets/Images/***.png"

Comment: i think the source is right becouse i can see the image on the designer

Comment: just worked fine close the visual studio and open it again i am  sorry  and Assets\Tiles\FlipCycleTileMedium.png will work not the full path

Answer (score 0):

This is the XAML Code I have used now: Just replace your MainPage.xaml with this code and run you app. You will see the image in the app definitely. Here's the screenshot.

[image]

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
x:Class="PhoneApp1.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Margin="12,0"/>
        <TextBlock Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Image Visibility="Visible" Source="Assets\Tiles\FlipCycleTileMedium.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="321" Margin="61,192,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="359"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```